# Bind Cascading dropdown when javascript is disable in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Is there any way to bind cascading dropdown in MVC even when browser javascript is disable.I'm able to bind using javascript but not found any solution when I disable my browser javascript

Comment: it is not a good idea , if so you can do it selected index change event use in MVC

Comment: You need to submit the form after selecting the first dropdown, then return a new view with both dropdowns.